# NextJS and bootstrap mobile nav

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, next.js

I'm using bootstrap with NextJS for my navbar but have one issue because of the dynamic page changes with React and Next on mobile view the menu stays open after clicking a link and loading new page.

Tried a few ways to try and make it close on page changes but been unsuccessful. What would be best way to achieve this?

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { ArrowDownCircle } from 'react-bootstrap-icons'
import logo from '../public/images/logo.gif'
import styles from '../styles/Navbar.module.scss'

const Navbar = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        import('bootstrap/js/dist/collapse')
        import('bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown')
    }, []);

    return (
        <nav id="navbar" className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light container">
            <div>
                <Link href="/" prefetch={false}><a className="navbar-brand">

                    <Image
                        src={logo}
                        alt="Logo"
                        layout="intrinsic"
                        width={200}
                        height={50}
                        priority={true}
                    />

                </a></Link>
            </div>

            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

                <ul className={`${styles.navLink} navbar-nav ms-auto`}>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link href="/" prefetch={false}><a className={`${styles.link} nav-link`} aria-current="page">Home</a></Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link href="/about" prefetch={false}><a className={`${styles.link} nav-link`}>About</a></Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a className={`${styles.link} nav-link`} id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Services <ArrowDownCircle className="ms-1" /></a>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><Link href="/web-design"><a className="dropdown-item">Web Design</a></Link></li>
                            <li><Link href="/web-development"><a className="dropdown-item">Web Development</a></Link></li>
                            <li><Link href="/ecommerce"><a className="dropdown-item">eCommerce</a></Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link href="/faq" prefetch={false}><a className={`${styles.link} nav-link`}>FAQ</a></Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link href="/contact" prefetch={false}><a className={`${styles.link} nav-link`}>Contact</a></Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <style jsx>{`
            a {
                background: none;
            }
            a:hover {
                background: none;
            }
            `}</style>
            
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for solution in 2022 or later, follow these steps:

*Note: This solution was tested on **NextJs (Typescript) + Bootstrap v.5.2***

1. Add an id to the button with class `navbar-toggler` i.e. `<button id="navbar-toggler" className="navbar-toggler" ...`
2. In your component class, say **Header.tsx**

Import `useRouter` and `useEffect`:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
```

and within your component function:

```
const Header = () => {

    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleRouteChange = (url: String) => {
            if (typeof window !== undefined && window.screen.width <= 991.98) { // change the width value according to your navbar breakpoint
                const navbar = document.getElementById("navbar-toggler");
                if (navbar !== null && !navbar.classList.contains('collapsed')) navbar.click()
            }
        }
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
    }, [router.events])

    return (<> ... other codes </>)

}

export default Header
```